# Assembly probing private path in new csproj format

Tags: c#, msbuild, csproj

I've recently finished converting a WPF project to the new csproj format which is much leaner.

However I have one missing piece left, adding a `probing` path for the assemblies, something that used to exist in the old `app.config` file. With this missing my application just doesn't find the required dlls.

The way I have this set up is with a Post-build event that clears and moves items to a bin folder:

```
SET folder=bin
rmdir "$(TargetDir)%folder%" /s /q
mkdir "$(TargetDir)%folder%"
move "$(TargetDir)*.dll" "$(TargetDir)%folder%\"
```

I've tried adding some entries to the .csproj file but to no avail. I believe this is more for compiling the application:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <ReferencePath>bin</ReferencePath>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup>
    <AssemblySearchPaths>
    $(AssemblySearchPaths);
    $(ReferencePath);
    </AssemblySearchPaths>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I guess my main question, should I still have an app.config, or is there a better .csproj approach available?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2"/>
  </startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="bin"/>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

My application will work if I include it, but I'd like to know if I can simplify this, or do this in a better way in general.